# C# Change Desktop Pattern

Tags: c#, user-interface, design-patterns, wallpaper

Im making a simple wallpaper changer. It works when changing the wallpaper but i cant change the pattern of the wallpaper. I tried something like this but it doesnt work :S

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKPATTERN, 0, "Center",
SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
```

Can some1 please show me the proper way of setting the wallpaper pattern?

Comment: Ozzy, It might be helpful for you to post some code so people can see how far you've gotten or if theres any potential problems in your code

Comment: it seems i asked the wrong question. I wanted to no how to position the wallpaper (center, stretch etc.) but setdeskpattern is not what i needed. I found out how to do it now tho :)

Comment: Well then I guess you could answer your own question so future searchers won't have to struggle to find an answer ;)

Comment: Bark at the moon! (sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: Or you could mark my answer as correct since i did answer the question you asked not the question you meant to ask.

Comment: i was always going to mark your answer correct crash :) i just wanted to understand more about it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean the centred/ streched / tiled setting   that would be the second past value int 1-3

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern Int32 SystemParametersInfo(UInt32 action, UInt32 uParam, String vParam, UInt32 winIni);
        private static readonly UInt32 SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14;
        private static readonly UInt32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
        private static readonly UInt32 SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

        private void SetWallpaper(string path)
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                Image imgInFile = Image.FromFile(path);
                try
                {
                    imgInFile.Save(SaveFile, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 3, SaveFile, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error in setting the wallpaper");
                }
                finally
                {
                    imgInFile.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: does this convert any image to a bmp? My solution about the tiled etc. thing was to edit the registry. is this way more efficient?

Comment: I don't know how your way works so i couldn't say, I do know this works pretty well.

I have another method to save files as a temporary bmp.

Comment: It appears i misspoke i do the transfer in this method with the imgInFile object